# Invalid Availability Zone when creating Instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to create instance on us-west-1c (though I get the same error when trying 1b, or any other AZ) and I'm getting this error:

```
Caught Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonEC2, AWS Error Code: InvalidParameterValue, AWS Error Message: Invalid availability zone: [us-west-1c]
Response Status Code: 400
Error Code: InvalidParameterValue
```

I can manually create the instance via the AWS console.  Here is my code to create that instance:

```
   runInstancesRequest =
            new RunInstancesRequest().withInstanceType("m1.medium")
                .withImageId("ami-37b1b45e").withMinCount(1).withMaxCount(1)
                .withSecurityGroupIds("launch-wizard-6")
                .withKeyName("testkey");

        Placement place = new Placement();
        place.setAvailabilityZone("us-west-1c");

        runInstancesRequest.setPlacement(place);

        RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
```

I've looked over this a hundred times, compared to other examples I've found online but I'm unable to identify the reason for this error.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each region in AWS is independent of the others, and the API endpoints are different.

It you aren't specifically configuring your code to send your request to the "us-west-1" region, then by default you're actually asking **us-east-1** to create the instance in an availability zone that it's never heard of.

> The AWS SDK for Java uses the US East (Northern Virginia) Region as the default region if you do not specify a region in your code.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-region-selection.html</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that. I set the endpoint before executing the code. After some more testing, I found setEndPoint to not be consistent. I shuffled my code around a bit and it started working.  Now, I'm fighting this delay between the API and AWS Console.  After creating an instance, even though I see it on the console, API returns that instance doesn't exist.  I have to stick in a 90 sec thread pause before it will detect it.