# Not able to create EBS in region/availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Trying to create an EBS block storage as:

```
aws ec2 create-volume --region us-west-1 --availability-zone us-west-2a --size 5 --volume-type gp2
```

But this is giving an error:

```
A client error (InvalidZone.NotFound) occurred when calling the CreateVolume operation: The zone 'us-west-2a' does not exist.
```

Looked at [Invalid Availability Zone when creating Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048081/invalid-availability-zone-when-creating-instance) but did not help.

What's the cause of this issue, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Why are you specifying the region --region us-west-1 in the command?

Comment: Your region and zone don't match. Are you trying to use us-west-1 or us-west-2?

Comment: Tried without `region` and got `A client error (InvalidZone.NotFound) occurred when calling the CreateVolume operation: The zone 'us-west-2a' does not exist.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the command what you are doing is you are specifying the Region `--region us-west-1` and creating the volume in `--availability-zone us-west-2a`. Thats why it is failing. Use this command instead and it will work.

```
aws ec2 create-volume --region us-west-2 --availability-zone us-west-2a --size 5 --volume-type gp2
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I tried creating a volume in `us-west-1a`. Turns out this AZ literally doesn't exist, there is only `us-west-1b` and `us-west-1c`. Run `aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region us-west-1` to check which AZs are available.